# VB.Net: Initiating variable and using like "with" at the same time?

Tags: vb.net

I have a class (let's say it's called Person) it has a property called Age and a sub called LogAccess.

I would like to make my code as small as possible and I was hoping for something like...

```
Using frm As New Person With {.Age = 30}
    .LogAccess()                        
End Using
```

Or maybe...

```
With New Person With {.Age = 30}
    .LogAccess()                        
End With
```

But that doesn't work.

Do I really have to type more code like...

```
Using p As New Person With {.Age = 30}
    With p
        .LogAccess()    
    End With                    
End Using
```

(using "With p" because there is many methods I have to call in my real project).

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you not just call `p.LogAccess()` and remove the `With`?

Comment: `"I would like to make my code as small as possible"` - This is very often a fool's errand.  Focus on making the code as *clear* as possible instead.

Comment: @Ric ... As I write, I'm using "With" because I call many methods at once ... and the code doesn't look "pretty" if I write ... p.SomeMethod1 p.SomeMethod2 p.SomeMethod3 etc. :)

Comment: @David ... my second code sample is much more clear than the third code sample IMO. :)

Comment: The first `with` is not a `with ... end with` statement, it's an object initializer.

Comment: Does your class need to dispose of any unmanaged resources?  If not, then the use of the Using method is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is just micro-optimization, which is not really necessary, but if you do want to make your code "small" just use:

```
Using p As New Person With {.Age = 30}
    p.LogAccess()
    ... 
End Using
```

Or

```
With New Person With {.Age = 30}
    .LogAccess()
    .AnotherMethod()
    ...
    .Dispose()                       
End With
```

But you lose the benefit of the `Using` statement.

Comment: Yeah I need the "Dispose" too. I guess it can't be done much more simpler than my third sample. But your last sample is the cleanest way IMO.

Comment: It's entirely down to personal preference, also might be worth considering ease of maintenance by others in the future!